# Real time message from windows service using wcf

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, real-time

I am presently working on .net 4 web application. In that there is a windows service .Using that windows service I am deleting 10 records at a time. These deletion message are shown to event viewer by number of records deleted. I want to show these messages at real time in web pages. Can I do 
this using wcf ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are allowed to use websockets use NetHttpBinding binding for wcf. By declaring a callback contract you can enable duplex communication over http that support websockets.

And also its worth mentioning SignalR which is the recommended way for websites to handle real time communication with the server that support it. SignalR can fallback to server sent events or long polling if websockets are not available.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619343/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part hope would help